# How to rebalance leader in cnosdb cluster mode

Tags: cnosdb

```
cnosdb 2.4.0, revision fcca4b4ba2d6e8759e202a89c412dd5cf4cb04b0
```

When a node in the cluster goes down and restarts, there will be a load imbalance phenomenon. The restarted node does not have a leader, so it does not bear any write and query loads. How to achieve rebalancing after this situation occurs